# Angular filter and ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular filter to limit characters on string output:

```
mod.filter('strLimit', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function (input, limit) {
   if (!input) return;
   if (input.length <= limit) {
     return input;
   }

   return $filter('limitTo')(input, limit) + '...';
  };
}]);
```

But when I apply it in combination with ng-bind-html, sometimes the filter truncates the output, like:

```
"This is a dummy string &ntil..."
```

I was be able to avoid this on PHP by using mb_substr instead of substr, so I need to know how can I fix this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way without ng-bind-html. I create another filter with the he library to filter the string before the cut:

```
mod.filter('htmlEntitiesDecode', function () {

 return function (html) {
  return he.decode(html);
 }

});
```

The library is this one: [he library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he)

So now I can use this way:

```
<p>{{ longString | htmlEntitiesDecode | strLimit : 50 }}</p>
```